# Returning the max of a column

Tags: sybase

Table:

```
SubSection | TradingId  | Year  | Amount
100A           5001       2004  -120
200B           5001       2005  -130
300C           5002       2006  -140
300C           5003       2007  -150
```

**I want to return the MAX Trading Id based on the subsection, I want this:**

```
SubSection | TradingId  | Year  | Amount
100A           5001       2004  -120
200B           5001       2005  -130
300C           5003       2007  -150
```

I tried selecting MAX with a GROUPBY Subsection, tried HAVING MAX etc but no luck

Comment: What version of Sybase? Not sure when [analytics/windowing functions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/BCGEEBHA.htm) first appeared.

Comment: also, should we assume that `SubSection, TracingId` is unique?

Comment: SubSection, TracingId are not unique

Comment: "are" or "is"? To be clear, I'm asking if `SubSection, TracingId` ***is*** unique - if the combination of the two is unique, not if either is unique on its own (which in any case wouldn't tally with your sample data).

Comment: thanks for the help jack,SubSection, TracingId is not unique

Comment: back to my first question then :-) what version are you running or does it support analytics eg dense_rank()?

Comment: and note that the given answers will return multiple rows per subsection given what you have said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM the_table t1
WHERE t1.trading_id = (SELECT max(t2.trading_id)
                    FROM the_table t2
                    WHERE t2.subsection = t1.subsection)
```

Comment: This will return all the subsections of the MAX(trading_id) for the table. Don't think it's the same with what OP asked.

Comment: No. It will only get the max(trading_id) for the "current" subsection because of the co-related sub-query

Comment: Ah, sorry, me dumb, you're right.

Comment: but it will return multiple rows per subsection if `subsection, trading_id` is not unique

Comment: @Jack - off course :-). But it still works as requested by OP. We work under current conditions..both queries return OP's desired output.

Comment: @Marian quite true :-) the sample data posted is pretty small though and I'm still left doubting what he really wants - I'll ask in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This will return all columns from the table, but for the max trading id of each subsection:

```
Select t2.*
from (
   Select max(TradingId) as MaxTradingId, SubSection
   from TableT
   group by SubSection
) t1 join TableT t2 on t1.MaxTradingId = t2.TradingId and t1.SubSection = t2.SubSection
```

Give it a try, please.

Comment: also assumes `subsection, trading_id` is unique, right?